# Pie Graph Click in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a graph that opens up a colorbox when a piece of the pie is selected.  However, I am trying to put permissions on this so that if a particular person is apart of an array of allowed pieces of the pie, then allow the click, otherwise ignore it.

Is there some advice you can give me that would point me in the right direction?

My array is called $allowedRegs, which would return NE, NW, SW, and the $person variable contains an employee Id number.  The getRegMgr() function should be returning the ID number of the allowed employee.  Is that allowed?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
            return {
                radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
                ]
            };
        });


$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        backgroundColor: null
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },

    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>${point.y}</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#000000',
                connectorColor: '#000000',
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
                events: {
                    click: function(e) {
                        //window.console.log(this);
                        var point       = e.point.name;
                        var explode     = point.split("~");
                        var loc         = explode[0];
                        var person      = <?php echo $respid;?>


                <?php 

                if(in_array($person, getRegMgr($allowedRegs))) {

                ?>              
                    $.colorbox({ iframe:true, width:"90%", height:"90%", href: "reportDetails.php?dept=<?php echo $dept;?>&fy=<?php echo $selectedFy;?>&location="+loc+"&person="+person});

                <?php } ?>

                    }
                },

        name: 'Total Revenue Earned:',
        data: [

                <?php
                    foreach($regionId as $region) {
                    //Get Data
                    $getData = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(hire_net) as rentalRev FROM dw_invoice LEFT JOIN dw_rep_zips ON dw_invoice.zip = dw_rep_zips.zip WHERE contract_type='H' and region = '".$region."' and invoice_date >= '".$fyStart."' AND invoice_date < '".$fyEnd."' GROUP BY region") or die("Cannot get data: " . mysql_error());

                    if(mysql_num_rows($getData) > 0) {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getData))
                            {
                            echo "['".getRegName($region)."', " . $row["rentalRev"]."], ";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            ]
    }]
});
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better is setting global variable in javascript, which value is getting form PHP. Then only what you need is add if in click event.

```
if(globalVariablePermission) 
  //do this
else
  return false;
```